# How can i add animations to existing UI components?

Tags: java, android, animation, sdk

How would Be able to add animations to normal buttons within an android application, I want the button to float from the button of the activity towards the top and then disappear.

I have looked into the animations library but it seems to me that it is intended for use with external animation that are imported into the project!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    button.animate().translationY(value).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    }).start();
```

You might need some calculation for the "value", or use translationYBy() with a distance.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it, I guess I will need to set the path that the component will travel in my self? do U think that should be aright?

Comment: Didn't quite understand what you mean. Isn't your path a straight line?

Answer (score 0):

in you res fodlder create new folder with name `anim` create new `xml` file there with `slide_up.xml` and put this code to it

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

then load animation like this

```
        Animation animSlideUp;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_fadein);

            txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
            btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

            // load the animation
            animSlideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.slide_up);

            // set animation listener
            animSlideUp.setAnimationListener(this);

            // button click event
            btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    txtMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // start the animation
                    txtMessage.startAnimation(animSlideUp);
                }
            });

        }

  @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Take any action after completing the animation

        // check for fade in animation
        if (animation == animSlideUp) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animation Stopped",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: Awesome! I guess the slide_up function will allow the component to float to the top? Many Thanks